# The drawing will not display when zoomed in to a certain level

Tags: javascript

When the source wrapX property in ol. interaction. Draw is set to true, it will appear that the drawing will not be displayed when zoomed in to a certain level.

It was found that in the source code, Draw. js did not process longitude values outside the normal range (-180 to 180) as normal values, ultimately resulting in coordinate points exceeding the range and not being recognized after zooming in for a certain level.

Looking forward to fixing this bug, there is no need for additional secondary development processing

```
if(xd<-180){
  if(Math.ceil(Math.abs(xd/180))%2 == 0){
    exentLin[j][0] = xd + Math.ceil(xd/-180)*180
  }else {
    exentLin[j][0] = xd -Math.ceil(xd/180)*180
  }
}else if(xd>180){
  if(Math.ceil(Math.abs(xd/180))%2 == 0){
    exentLin[j][0] = xd + -Math.ceil(xd/180)*180
  }else {
    exentLin[j][0] = xd + -Math.ceil(xd/180)*180 +180
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, maybe consider to re-formulate your question, so that it contains the following information: What are you trying to accomplish (=> Is this a map or something)? What "drawing"? Where is that "wrapX property" you talk about? What is the "bug" exactly (=> At which "level" does "the drawing" disappear)? The code you posted seems to solve the range problems you mentioned - or does it not?